Trying to install Microsoft.Data.SqlClient fails on .NET 8.0.204
After creating a brand new console project with .NET 8.0.204
When I run:
dotnet add package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient --version 5.2.0

It fails installing the package with the following error:
Determining projects to restore...
Writing C:\Users\alamadrid\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpfoxkvh.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for code signing.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET for timestamping.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' into project 'C:\Users\alamadrid\Documents\Projects\STATMiniAgentLinux\STATMiniAgentLinux.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\Users\alamadrid\Documents\Projects\STATMiniAgentLinux\STATMiniAgentLinux.csproj...


error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient (>= 5.2.0)' for 'net8.0'.
error: Package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\Users\alamadrid\Documents\Projects\STATMiniAgentLinux\STATMiniAgentLinux.csproj'.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.2.0 should support .NET 8.0.204, as that's what it says on the release notes of that version.
Release Notes
Whats a little more strange is that I couldnt find anyone online having the same issue as me.
Please see below my csproj file.
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>


What is the TargetFramework inside the project file? Is it net8.0 or is net8.0-??? also I believe this library has been replaced by System.Data.SqlClient

Can you please share your csproj file?

@RyanThomas it is the other way around, System.Data.SqlClient is replaced by Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

@GuruStron and Ryan please find the csproj in the question.

@AlvaroLamadridGomez was not able to repro, works just fine for me. Possibly you have problems with your nuget config,

@GuruStron it just worked on another machine.

I tried the installation again in another machine and I no longer have that error. Seems like some issues with Nuget.
